# drawing flow chart using php

Tags: php, imagick, flowchart

I want to dynamically create a visual flow chart using php on web.

I tried to use iMagick extension to draw rectangles, lines, and etc.

However, I ran into a problem that all the drawings have to be on an image and that makes my html code not appear on screen.

So I searched if there is a flow chart extension or functions I can use which I failed.

Is there any flow chart making library/application that I can use with php to dynamically draw flow chart on web?

If not, is there a way to have plain html texts above the image I created with iMagick extension so I can see my html texts positioned at the same spot as the rectangles I made using iMagick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is generally done is you have two files, one with the page contents, and the other that is the image, then you embed the image like you would a regular image (`<img>` tags).

Say you have index.php which is your main page, and you have image.php that has your flowchart code. On index.php you embed the image like this:

```
<img src="image.php" alt="flowchart" />
```